# IJVM using a local variable for GOTO statement

Tags: jvm, bytecode, goto

I am working with IJVM and trying to use the GOTO instruction using a local variable in place of a static offset (or label). It won't work. I suppose it is simply treating the variable name as a label and trying to branch to it, but no such label exists. Is there any way I can force it to read the contents of the variable (which contains an offset), or some other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, JVM bytecode doesn't let you jump to arbitrary instructions based on the contents of a variable.  This restriction makes it possible for the JVM to verify various security properties of the bytecode by statically enumerating all control paths through a particular method.  If you were able to jump anywhere, the static analyzer couldn't prove that all necessary program invariants held.

If you do need to jump to an arbitrary index, consider looking into the `tableswitch` or `lookupswitch` instructions, which would let you enumerate possible destinations in advance.  It's not exactly what you're looking for, but to the best of my knowledge the sort of arbitrary jump you're trying to make isn't possible in JVM bytecode.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, for the class I'm in we're just using IJVM so I don't believe the tableswitch and lookupswitch instructions are available to me. Wouldn't this mean that it is not possible to create a method which takes an offset as a parameter and branch to that offset? It's odd, because my assignment is asking me to do this :(.

Answer (score 0):

The GOTO instruction is implemented in MIC1. It interprets the 2 bytes after the opcode as an offset to the PC at the start of the instruction.

I think that the assignment must be asking you to write a new GOTO in MIC1 that interprets the byte after the opcode as the offset to a local variable that contains the branch offset.